# Automatically running a program not in main folder

Tags: autorun

What is the correct code to open a program inside another folder using autorun? say the computer assigns the drive as D:, and thus the program would be at D:\folder\program.exe then would the command be

`open=.\folder\program.exe`

?

Comment: Try asking this question on the superuser site.  This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work because `.` or nothing maps to the current folder.

I would think it would just be:

```
open=\folder\program.exe
```

`\` maps to the root, watch out because this could map through the system drive though.

To be sure, you might want to use:

```
open=D:\folder\program.exe
```